# Qlik Sense: why am I getting Out of Calculation Memory error?

Tags: qliksense

Here is my data load:

[image]

And when I try to load my visualizations (which are just straight tables), I get this every time:

[image]

I've continued reducing my data in my SQL by shortening the date filter to only go back so far, but I'm at a point now where I really can't see shortening it any further.

One idea I had was maybe I need to load my data into QVD's, but I really don't have a good understanding of these. Would it make sense to load my Qlik tables (Login, PNA, Action, etc.) into QVD's and then drop the tables? Would that alleviate my memory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to load data from QVD files will not change anything. QVD files are just data storage that is native to Qlik and if used correctly loading data from them is much faster than sourcing the data from somewhere else (DB for example)

`Out of calculation` memory usually means exactly this - not enough memory to calculate the object.

By default each object (hypercube) have a limit of how much memory the cube is allowed to use while being evaluated/calculated. And if the object is "heavy" and starts to consume more memory than this limit then Qlik will abort the evaluation and will throw such an error.

By "heavy" I mean objects that:

- are showing too much data - too many columns and too many rows
- having some twisted calculations - especially aggregations
- all of the above

My suggestion is to:

- start removing/disabling the expressions and dimensions one by one and identify the combination that breaks the object
- put some calculation conditions on the table - only calculate the object when specific criteria's are met.F or example: show the object if there is a selection in the `Country` field. This will prevent the object to show data for all countries and the object will operate on smaller data set (and will need less memory)
- re-evaluate the data model (if possible) and the expressions (if possible) to optimize the data model to be more efficient. Usually im ending up with this scenario

P.S. Qlik have a setting of the objects memory limit. By default this value is `0`. Which means that Qlik will apply some internal logic and will try and protect the machine from running low on resources. If this setting is disabled then its possible your object calculation to be completed but its also possible that the object calculation to consume all of the available resources and essentially can crash the machine.
Also this setting is **global** for the whole Qlik instance. And if disabled then all the objects in all the apps will "benefit" from it. So if you are in server environment then any app can potentially crash the server.
Thats a long way of saying - **use it at your own risk**

Comment: This is quite helpful, thank you.